# Unrecognized font family 'Material Design Icons'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I have added UIAppFonts in My info.plist.

I have deleted node modules and reinstalled it and also did same with the pods.

I have did pod install. Icons are working in Android but not in IOS.

My Full Project Link = "https://github.com/Pratikgaikwad1004/movizrate-movie-rating-patform".

Please help me, tell me what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in Podfile

`pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'`

and

`cd ios`

and

`pod install`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-load the fonts you need to use when the app initialize.

Inside your app top-level entry file `App.js`

Add those lines

```js
//... other app imports

import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

// Pre-load material icons and other icon sets app use

MaterialCommunityIcons.loadFont();


//... other remaining code
```